# Is there an easy way to do half open TCP connection via Python Asyncio?

Tags: python, asynchronous, tcp, async-await, python-asyncio

I'm just picking up some **async** Python and trying to write a simple **TCP port scanner** using the **Asyncio** module.

I can open a full-fledged **TCP** connection with *3-way* handshakes via `asyncio.open_connection`. However, I want to create an **SYN-ACK** half-open ***connection***—similar to what **nmap** uses—using asyncio. I was rummaging through the **streams** API but couldn't find anything. Is there a high-level method to do this? If not, how do I do this?

Comment: You can't do this with 100% pure Java.

Comment: Where did Java come from?

Answer (score 1):

asyncio doesn't give you such control on TCP/IP stack layers and even hides some complex tasks such as callbacks, low-level protocols, transports.
You can do it using a raw socket.

Modules that can be useful

- python-nmap
- scapy